# Double induction example: $ 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + \cdots + q^{n-1} + q^n = \frac {q^{n+1}-1}{q-1} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, induction, geometric-series

I'm working on a double induction problem with the following prompt:

> Prove by induction on $n$ that for any real number $q > 1$ and integer $n \ge 0$:
>   $$ 1 + q + q^2 + q^3 + \cdots + q^{n-1} + q^n = \frac {q^{n+1}-1}{q-1} $$

Based on [Induction on two integer variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7660/induction-on-two-integer-variables), I would imagine the solution is:

1. Base case $(q,n)$ as $(2,n)$ and $(q,0)$
2. Assume premise for $(2,n)$ and prove $n+1$
3. Assume premise for $(q,0)$ and prove $q+1$

But even the base cases confuse me...for example on $(q,0)$:
$$1+q^0 = \frac {q^{0+1}-1}{q-1} $$
$$2 = 1 $$

That can't right. Maybe I omit the $q^0$ on the LHS, but why?

Comment: It would be more clear if you wrote your question prompt as: "$q^0 + q^1 + \dots\ $" as opposed to "$1 + q^1 + \dots\ $"

Comment: ah...so obvious. thanks.

Comment: Slightly relevant: you can see my answer on [this thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1131164/divisibility-proof-with-induction-stuck-on-induction-step) for a proof that uses double induction (just to get you exposed to how the mechanics of a proof using double induction might work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dfrac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}+q^{n+1}=\dfrac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}+\dfrac{q^{n+2}-q^{n-1}}{q-1}=\dfrac{q^{n+2}-1}{q-1}$$
and
$$q^0=1=\dfrac{q^{0+1}-1}{q-1}$$
That's a proof by induction I think.

Comment: Ah, I see my problem. I was trying to divide $q^{n+1}$ by $q-1$ but I should have been _multiplying_ it. This and the reply from @jameselmore sealed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

The problem says *"for any* ***real*** *number $q>1$..."* You can't do (standard) mathematical induction on the real numbers ([see here though](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4202/264)).

As the problem itself explicitly states, you are supposed to do induction on $n$. There is no "double induction" here. The number $q$ should be treated as just a given real number.

Answer (score 4):

There is no double induction, as there is only one variable running through the natural numbers.

You can just leave $q$ as an indeterminate; note that the expression is
$$
q^0+q^1+\dots+q^n
$$
and this means that, for $n=0$, it is just $q^0=1$. So the base step is true.

For the inductive step,
$$
q^0+q^1+\dots+q^n+q^{n+1}=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}+q^{n+1}=
\frac{q^{n+1}-1+q^{n+2}-q^{n+1}}{q-1}
$$
and you're done.

The only restriction on $q$ is $q\ne1$ (somebody would say also for $q=0$, but if we consider $0^0=1$ the relation still holds).