# The argument of a proof based on double induction

Tags: induction

I am struggling to convince myself of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12114) proof. Let me rewrite it so that the proof's structure and my interpretation of it are more apparent.

Let $ S(k, n) $ be true when $ n! \mid P(k, n) $ where $ P(k, n) = (k+1)(k+2)\cdots(k+n) $. We want to show that $ S(k, n) $ holds for all $ k, n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} $. (I consider only the positive integers to simplify the discussion.)

Induction on $ n $:

1. The base case $ S(k, 1) $ holds since $ 1! \mid (k + 1) $ for all $ k $
2. The inductive step on $ n $ is not demonstrated yet, but the inductive hypothesis $ H_0 $ is introduced: $ (n-1)! \mid P(k, n-1) $
3. Induction on $ k $:

   1. The base case $ S(0, n) $ holds since $ P(0, n) = n! $
   2. The inductive step $ H_1 $ on $ k $ assumes $ n! \mid P(k, n) $
   3. Consider $$ \begin{align}
          P(k+1, n) & = ((k+1)+1)((k+1)+2)\cdots((k+1)+(n-1))((k+1)+n) \\
                  & = [(k+2)(k+3)\cdots(k+n)](k+1) + [(k+2)\cdots(k+n)]n \\
                  & = P(k, n) + nP(k+1, n-1)
         \end{align} $$
   4. The first term $ P(k, n) $ is divisible by $ n! $ by $ H_1 $
   5. The second term $ nP(k+1, n-1) $ is also divisible by $ n! $:

      1. By $ H_0 $ we have $ (n-1)! \mid P(k+1, n-1) $
      2. Then $ n $ times a multiple of $ (n-1)! $ is divisible by $ n! $
   6. Therefore, $ S(k+1, n) $ holds

I do not see what makes step 3.5.1 valid. How can one use $ S(k+1, n-1) $ during the induction step when neither $ H_0 \equiv S(k, n-1) $ nor $ H_1 \equiv S(k, n) $ are stated in terms of $ k + 1 $?

Please note that I understand the inductive argument on $ [ k + n = z ] \to [ k + n = z + 1 ] $ as presented in the [alternative](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1786578) answer. Such argument also holds for the proof in question, but this is not how the author structured it. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1542491) answer, the proof appears to use simple induction twice. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1132601) proof for an example of such argument. From what I can see, it does not use $ \ell+1 $ during the induction step on the second variable $ \ell $.

Comment: The inductive hypothesis in the induction on $n$ is that $S(i, n)$ is true for **all** $i$, so it can be used for $i=k$ or $k + 1$ anything you like in the inner induction on $k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to elaborate on the argument between 2 and 3.

> The inductive step on n is not demonstrated yet, but the inductive hypothesis $H_0$ is introduced: $(n−1)!∣P(k,n−1)$ **for all** $k \in \mathbb{N}$

I added the **for all** $k\in \mathbb{N}$. We are assuming that everything works perfectly for $n-1$ (this is the nature of induction).

Perhaps a better way is to just frame this in terms of the proposition we're trying to prove: You've already shown that $S(k,0)$ holds for all $k$, so now we will assume inductively that $S(k,n-1)$ holds for all $k$.

For the next step, you say we are going to use

> Induction on k

but specifically what proposition are we proving here? As per the proof by induction format, we're trying to prove $S(k,n)$, where $n$ is some fixed value, and we know $S(j,n-1)$ is true for all $j$ (note the change of variable here, so as not to cause confusion).

Now hopefully it's clear why you can use $S(j,n)$, where $j = k+1$: it's simply part of the inductive hypothesis.