# Represent $N$ as the sum of exactly $K$ distinct positive integers

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, integer-partitions

You are given two integers $N$ and $K$. Find all ways to represent $N$ as the sum of exactly $K$ distinct positive integers $x_1,x_2, \ldots,x_K$ — in other words.

$xi_>0$ for each valid $i$;

$x_i \neq x_j$ for each valid $i \neq j$;

$x_1+x_2+ \ldots +x_K=N$

For Example : $N=15$ and $K=3$

Answer should be: $1+2+12, 1+3+11, 1+4+10, 1+5+9, 1+6+8, 2+3+10, 2+4+9, 2+5+8, 2+6+7, 3+4+8, 3+5+7, 4+5+6$

How to code to generate these combinations in any language?

Comment: Search the web for _code to generate integer partitions_. Here's a python solution (does not require distinct parts, but could be modified) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035752/elegant-python-code-for-integer-partitioning

Comment: Finding distinct positive integers is the main concern along with less Time Complexity. Its good to get solution for what is asked in the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fascinating induction problem with numerous interpretations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1115105/fascinating-induction-problem-with-numerous-interpretations)

Answer (score 3):

Are you currently participating in SnackDown Round 1B, Then you should not ask this question before the competition ends, you are violating the codechef code of conduct for the competition.

Comment: If this problem is drawn from an open contest, then you should vote to close it on those grounds.  Hit flag at the bottom of the question, select in need of moderator intervention, and then explain that this is an open contest question in the dialog box, which will alert the moderators that this question is drawn from an open contest, which is a violation of site rules.

Comment: Now the Contest was ended. Please give answer to my question.